# Circle shaped, dynamic view with AutoLayout

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, calayer

Before AutoLayout I could do a view cut to a circle shape with setting `.layer.cornerRadius` to half of the view's height.

Now, using AutoLayout how can I achieve, to my view keep look like a circle?

I have already tried and failed:

- using KVO to find out when `frame` changes. It gets called, but at that point setting `cornerRadius` on the view does not have any effect
- calling `-setNeedsLayout` to have frame values before I set `cornerRadius` (does not work either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the property `masksToBounds` on the layer.

```
xyz.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Further, the reason why this actually won't affect Auto Layout is because the view's frame will remain the same regardless of its corner radius.